# getting name of object passed as function argument as string to put in output path

Tags: python, string, function, variables, arguments

I have a function to print a pandas df to .csv. I pass the df (`my_data`) to the function as an argument which specifies `data` as parameter. In the output, the .csv file name is hardcoded as string.

How could I write code that will take the name of the input variable (in this case `my_data`) and parse into the output string so that the function can be called with various dataframes and always output to .csv with the input df name? I read several posts and came across varname methods such as Wrapper or nameof, inspect module and others, but I couldn't get a solution yet.

The code below:

```
def print_to_file(data):
    while True:
        try:
            query = input("Do you want to save data to file (Y/N)?")
            valid = ("Y", "N")
            if query in valid:
                pass
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter (Y/N)")
        break
    if query == "Y":
        data.to_csv("data.csv")


print_to_file(my_data)
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. What happens when you want to use a file name with a space in it? If you want a file named `California 2024 Rainfall.csv`, you can't call a variable `California 2024 Rainfall`. What happens when you want to take a list of dataframes and print every element to a file? `for df in dataframes: print_to_file(df)` gives all of them the same name. What happens when you want to wrap this function in a helper function? The argument name is always the same when the helper function calls `print_to_file`.